# Problemas deserializando con .json

Tags: c#, json

Estoy creando un programa que lee la información de un archivo .txt y lo muestra por pantalla. Adjunto el código:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\sergi\OneDrive\Escritorio\PROGRAMACIÓN\LeerTexto.txt"))
            {
                string texto;

                while ((texto = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    Producto producto = new Producto(); 
                    producto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Producto>(texto); 
                    textBoxNombre.Text = producto.Nombre; 
                    textBoxID.Text = producto.ID; 
                    textBoxCategoria.Text = producto.Categoría; 
                    textBoxDescripcion.Text = producto.Descripción; 

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(MessageBoxIcon.Error + "El archivo no ha podido ser leído"  );               
        }

    }
```

El string que obtiene es este:

> {"Nombre": "Manzana verde", "ID": "6541986", "Categoría": "Frutas y verduras", "Descipción": "Una manzana verde autóctona de Puigcerdá"}

No sé porque lo deserializa bien y muestra por pantalla todos los datos, menos la descripción. ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Lo más fácil es que el texto dentro del archivo esté formateado a Json y luego (con ayuda de https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) lo parseas a una clase.

Comment: Es necesario que tus datos estén en un .txt? te aconsejo que uses .json como indica @CamiloBernal de esa forma lo puedes deserealizar solo asignándole el modelo de clase a la variable donde tengas tus datos.

Comment: Realmente la extensión del archivo no es importante, puede ser .txt, .json, .whatever... lo que si es recomendable es que la "notación" del contenido del archivo sea json.

Comment: @CamiloBernal @vcasas ¡gracias por vuestros consejos! Al final he creado esta clase:    
`class Producto
        {
           public string Nombre { get; set; }
           public string ID { get; set; }
           public string Categoría { get; set; }
           public string Descripción { get; set; }
        }`

Comment: y dentro del while he puesto:
`Producto producto = new Producto();
                       producto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Producto>(texto);
                        textBoxNombre.Text = producto.Nombre;
                        textBoxID.Text = producto.ID;
                        textBoxCategoria.Text = producto.Categoría;
                        textBoxDescripcion.Text = producto.Descripción;
                    }`
No se porque me funcionan todos menos la Descripción...

Comment: El string que obtiene el StreamReader es este: {"Nombre": "Manzana verde", "ID": "6541986", "Categoría": "Frutas y verduras", "Descipción": "Una manzana verde autóctona de Puigcerdá"}

Comment: Te recomiendo [edit] tu pregunta y actualices con lo nuevo para que sea más facil ver cómo quedó finalmente y entender porqué falla.